# Save file to sdcard as3 Air for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am making an android application in Air for android using actionscript 3. I need to download  a file from the server and save it to mobile sdcard. Following is my code, the file gets loaded from the server but how do I save it on sdcard?

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
var urlString:String = "http://www.mywebsite.com/xyz/myswftodownload.swf";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
urlStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
urlStream.load(urlReq);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
    urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
    trace("Loaded");
    urlStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    urlStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded); 
    //NOW HOW TO SAVE THE LOADED FILE ON SDCARD??
}

function onProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
var nPercent:Number = Math.round((evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal) * 100);    
//loadingAnim.bar.scaleX = nPercent / 100;
status.text = nPercent.toString() + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
//NOW HOW TO SAVE THE LOADED FILE ON SDCARD
var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("myswftodownload.swf");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
fileStream.close();
```

File.userDirectory usually points to the sdcard (external storage). But beware of the fact that external storage doesn't have to be available at all time (for example when device connected as mass storage by usb).

In your case i would consider using internal storage instead and use File.applicationDirectory or File.applicationStorageDirectory for saving your swf files. External storage is better for saving files like images, music, documents..

Comment: My code is now working but I am running into a new problem now. I cannot read the swf that was saved. When I check that the file exists, it returns true but does not load the same. :(

Comment: You probably neet to set application context to current one when loading the SWF